# C# Add to a List Asynchronously in API

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an API which needs to be run in a loop for Mass processing.

Current single API is:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<CombinedAddressResponse>> GetCombinedAddress(AddressRequestDto request)
```

We are not allowed to touch/modify the original single API. However can be run in bulk, using foreach statement. What is the best way to run this asychronously without locks?

Current Solution below is just providing a list, would this be it?

```
public async Task<ActionResult<List<CombinedAddressResponse>>> GetCombinedAddress(List<AddressRequestDto> requests)
{
   var combinedAddressResponses = new List<CombinedAddressResponse>();
   foreach(AddressRequestDto request in requests)
   {
      var newCombinedAddress = (await GetCombinedAddress(request)).Value; 
      combinedAddressResponses.Add(newCombinedAddress);

   }
   return combinedAddressResponses;
}
```

**Update:**

In debugger, it has to go to `combinedAddressResponse.Result.Value`

```
combinedAddressResponse.Value = null
```

and Also strangely, writing `combinedAddressResponse.Result.Value gives error below "Action Result does not contain a definition for for 'Value' and no accessible extension method`

[image]

Comment: What's wrong with this code again?  Looks like it should work to me.  I guess I'm not understanding what your question is.  There exists no _definitive_ Right Way way to do something asynchronously (whether it's using async/await or something else).

Comment: But this executes the API for each request sequentially. Consider using `Parallel.For` or `Parallel.ForEach` (`System.Threading.Tasks`) instead. Also, List<T> is not thread safe. You need to lock, or to use a concurrent collection.

Comment: @OguzOzgul Thread safety of list is irrelevant here.  The `Add` method is called only after the async operation is complete because of `await`.  There's no need to lock or use a concurrent collection here.

Comment: hi @OguzOzgul  can you provide in solution, with some sample code,  and I can send points ? thanks

Comment: @Zer0 yes it is here, but not when using Parallel. I think I misunderstood the question. When seeing that BULK word, I though what OP wants to achieve was parallel execution of the API. Otherwise yes, API is awaited one by one for each record, adding to the list is no problem.

Comment: @OguzOzgul Ah, gotcha.  Yeah, this will, effectively, run the requests sequentially.  As-is, the code is thread-safe but it's not really doing "many requests at once".  It's doing "many requests, one by one".  Probably what the OP is trying to change.  And there's a big difference.

Comment: Dear @AlanSmith548, we need to understand your requirement clearly first. Your code seems completely fine and should execute without problems. Are you looking for a way to speed things up by executing the single API for many records in parallel? Or are you just looking for a way to execute the API for many records sequentially? (Which you already seem to have achieved)

Comment: hi @OguzOzgul looking for a way to speed things up and run in parallel thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm writing this code off the top of my head without an IDE or sleep, so please comment if I'm missing something or there's a better way.

But effectively I think you want to run all your requests at once (not sequentially) doing something like this:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<List<CombinedAddressResponse>>> GetCombinedAddress(List<AddressRequestDto> requests)
{
   var combinedAddressResponses = new List<CombinedAddressResponse>(requests.Count);
   var tasks = new List<Task<ActionResult<CombinedAddressResponse>>(requests.Count);
   foreach (var request in requests)
   {
      tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () => await GetCombinedAddress(request));
   }
   //This waits for all the tasks to complete
   await tasks.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());
   combinedAddressResponses.AddRange(tasks.Select(x => x.Result.Value));
   return combinedAddressResponses;
}
```

Comment: gave thumbs up and from coworker also, other answer was working little more optimal, than you

Answer (score 1):

> looking for a way to speed things up and run in parallel thanks

What you need is "asynchronous concurrency". I use the term "concurrency" to mean "doing more than one thing at a time", and "parallel" to mean "doing more than one thing at a time using threads". Since you're on ASP.NET, you don't want to use additional threads; you'd want to use a form of concurrency that works asynchronously (which uses fewer threads). So, `Parallel` and `Task.Run` should not be parts of your solution.

The way to do asynchronous concurrency is to build a collection of tasks, and then use `await Task.WhenAll`. E.g.:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<IReadOnlyList<CombinedAddressResponse>>> GetCombinedAddress(List<AddressRequestDto> requests)
{
  // Build the collection of tasks by doing an asynchronous operation for each request.
  var tasks = requests.Select(async request =>
  {
    var combinedAddressResponse = await GetCombinedAdress(request);
    return combinedAddressResponse.Value;
  }).ToList();

  // Wait for all the tasks to complete and get the results.
  var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
  return results;
}
```

Comment: its giving me error, the await operator can only be used with an async lambda expression, so adding it in edit

Comment: add update above with picture error, trying to fix it, getting close